# Preventing windows from reconfiguring graphics on boot

Tags: windows, group-policy, configuration, graphics

Got a bunch of Windows boxes, each with two nvidia video cards, and each with either three or four monitors, that will every once in a while decide to rearrange the displays when the box is turned on.  This happens about once a month on one or another of the boxes at random.  How can I prevent this from occuring, that is, tell Windows 'this is how I want the graphics and display configuration to be for all time.  Whether the monitor is there or not or the graphics card is there or not or no matter what.  Period.  Full Stop.  The End.  So quit trying to help me."

Can this be set by a GPO in active directory?

thx,

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a display profile in nvidia control panel. You can create profiles for specific applications etc too.

If that isn't what your looking for, have a go with DisplayFusion.

http://www.displayfusion.com/

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at profiles.  Display fusion is -not- something that we want available to users.  Less options is better.  "It just works the same way every time no changes or surprises" is what they (and we) want.

Comment: Cool. Check if nView Desktop Management Software is installed and run with that: http://www.nvidia.com/object/nview_display_us.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that GPO is capable of controlling. It sounds like you either have a BIOS/EFI issue (not detecting the hardware properly/in order at boot) or a driver problem. Try updating to the latest of each.

Comment: Well, that's too bad.  It's not the first time I've screamed that I want a 'quit trying to help me!!' setting for windows.  Thanks though.

Comment: I've had never-ending issues with EFI in these scenarios. Especially with USB mice ending up in endless loops trying to install after working perfectly for months. After resetting to defaults in BIOS, issue still comes back. Sigh.